# *-homomorphisms from $L^\infty(0, 1)$ to itself that acts as the identity on continuous functions

Tags: von-neumann-algebras, lebesgue-measure

Let $\pi: L^\infty([0, 1], \lambda) \rightarrow L^\infty([0, 1], \lambda)$ be a *-homomorphism (where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $[0, 1]$), not necessarily normal (otherwise the question is trivial). Suppose further that $\pi|_{C([0, 1])} = Id_{C([0, 1])}$. Is it possible for $\pi$ to be not normal or equivalently for $\pi$ to not be the identity map?

Comment: Here’s an equivalent formulation of the question that I’m aware of, though I highly doubt this formulation is of any help: Let $\Lambda$ be the spectrum of $L^\infty(0, 1)$, $\phi: [0, 1] \rightarrow \Lambda$ be a measurable map, where $[0, 1]$ is equipped with the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets and $\Lambda$ is equipped with the $\sigma$-algebra of Baire sets. Suppose for each $t \in [0, 1]$, $\phi(t)$ is a character extending evaluation at $t$ on $C([0, 1])$. Does it follow that for any compact $G_\delta$ subset $K \subseteq \Lambda$ with no interior, $\phi^{-1}(K)$ is null?

Comment: No $\pi$ has to the identity map. Every state on a von Neumann algebra uniquely decomposes into a normal part and a singular part. A state $f$ on a von Neumann algebra $M$ is singular iff there is a net $p_n$ of projections such that $f(p_n)=1$ and $p_n\searrow0$. It follows that every *-representation of a von Neumann algebra $M$ on a separable Hilbert space uniquely decomposes into a normal part and a singular part. A singular *-homomorphism $\sigma$ is such that there is a net $p_n\searrow0$ and $\sigma(1-p_n)=0$.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA I'm a little bit confused as to how the decomposition into singular and normal parts imply the result? I mean, there exists closed nowhere dense subsets $F \subset [0, 1]$ of measure arbitrarily close to 1, so if we fix an increasing sequence $F_n$ of such sets with measure converging to 1 and let $p_n = \chi_{[0, 1] \setminus F_n}$, then $p_n \searrow 0$. But as $F_n$ is nowhere dense, $1 - p_n = \chi_{F_n}$ does not majorize any nontrivial positive continuous functions, so I'm not seeing any immediate issue posed by $\sigma(1 - p_n) = 0$.

Comment: You are right. It's unclear.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA Prof. Ozawa, do you know if a weaker version of this, something like the following, holds? Does there exist an intermediate $C^*$-algebra $A$, $C([0, 1]) \subseteq A \subseteq L^\infty(0, 1)$, and a *-homomorphism $\pi: A \rightarrow L^\infty(0, 1)$ such that $\pi$ is not the inclusion map $A \subseteq L^\infty(0, 1)$ but it is the inclusion map when restricted to $C([0, 1])$?